# Error: no receivers for action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.registration

Tags: android

I am using the following code in my Manifest

```
    <receiver 
     android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" 
     android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.moosejawford.activities" />
     </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

It worked well before, but suddenly from today I am getting this error, did google changed anything.

Please help me in solving this issue. I have not found any correct answers in google.I just likes to know why it is happening like this.

Error report:

```
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at com.moosejawford.activities.Tabs.onCreate(Tabs.java:44)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    ... 11 more
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No receivers for action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkReceiver(GCMRegistrar.java:169)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(GCMRegistrar.java:154)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-26 11:30:18.031: E/AndroidRuntime(32283):    ... 28 more
```

Comment: GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this); use this to check if your manifest file is correct.

Comment: where should I keep this

Comment: in your activity after setcontentview. "checkManifest(Context context)
Checks that the application manifest is properly configured."

Comment: I am getting this error in Google nexus device,its working good in Motorolo Droid

Comment: Btw c2dm is obsolete and deprecated. Its been replaced by GCM.

Comment: I just restarted my device,its working fine.I have one more problem with spinners and tabs,can you please suggest me

Comment: You can post one more question... :)

Comment: @user2717010 so restarting the device works to solve it? I sometimes have this crash with other users.